# PHP MySQL - Send email alert when a new record is added but

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need to send an email alert when a new record is added but the table also has input fields and i dont need an alert when a user edits those input field.

I have a database that is used for equipment delivery dates. A user will schedule a delivery for a piece of equipment and then enter the date into a back-end database(SQL Server).

I created a php application that looks at the backend database and puts the total number of deliveries on a jquery calendar.

[image]

When the user clicks on a particular day on the calendar, it pulls up a table that shows the following:

```
Date
Equipment
Customer
```

I then created a mysql table which pushes that information into my local msyql table with the following fields:

```
AssignedPerson
Status
Comments
```

The user can then make their notes to the delivery.

The problem is sometimes the delivery dates change or a new delivery is added and we're not aware unless we constantly check the php app.

I want to send an alert when a new record is added but i dont need an alert when a user updates the table.

Here's the code i have for when a user updates the table.  Again i only when an alert for when a new record is added to the mysql table from SQL backend database:

```
    include('./PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

    servername_wamp = "localhost";
    $username_wamp = "root";
    $password_wamp = "";



           if(isset($_POST['id']))
           {
            $id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
            $AssignedPerson=mysql_escape_String($_POST['AssignedPerson']);
            $ShipDate=mysql_escape_String($_POST['ShipDate']);
            $Status=mysql_escape_String($_POST['Status']);
            $Numofmachines=mysql_escape_String($_POST['Numofmachines']);
            $Model=mysql_escape_String($_POST['Model']);


            $a = mysql_connect($servername_wamp, $username_wamp, $password_wamp) or die(mysql_error());
            $b = mysql_select_db('orders', $a) or die(mysql_error());

            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderNumber='$OrderNumber' LIMIT 1",$a) or die(mysql_error());
            $rs=mysql_fetch_row($result2);
       if ($rs) {


if (($rs['ShipDate_log']=='')&&($Status=='Assigned')) {
$sd=", ShipDate_log='".$ShipDate."'";


    $message1982 = "
            <ul>

            <li> <strong>ID:</strong> $id  </li>
            <li> <strong><font color='red'>Tech:</font></strong> $AssignedPerson   </li>
            <li> <strong>Ship Date:</strong> $ShipDate </li>
            <li> <strong>Customer:</strong> $Customer </li>
            <li> <strong>Status:</strong> $Status </li>
            <li> <strong>Sales Rep:</strong> $SalesRep  </li>
            <li> <strong>Order Number:</strong> $OrderNumber</li>
            <li> <strong>Number Of Machines:</strong> $Numofmachines </li>


            </ul>
            "; 







$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$body             = $message1982;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // authentication enabled

$mail->Host = "10.10.10.38";
$mail->Port = 25; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom("nservice2@everyone.com");
$address = "bot@everyone.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John");
$mail->Subject    = ''. $Customer. ' Ticket Assigned';

$mail->MsgHTML($body);






if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: so what seems to be the problem? you've pointed out what you'd like and not like to do.  a trigger maybe? if that's what the question's about

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices.

Comment: I also have no idea why you're escaping values that are used for display. The correct function for that is [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: So what part of what you want are you missing (or is causing an error)? I understand your program, the explanation was fine, though it's just missing an explanation pinpointing where you are having your issue. You dont want a popup for changing dates, but where is the popup you made? is the problem you have not knowing how to create the popup? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people add columns like `created_at` and `updated_at`. When creating a record, you can assign both of these columns the same value. If these values are equal, it's a brand new record. If they're different, then it is an existing record that has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

during the insertion create a small script that connects with google mailing services or any other choice and send an email using a predefined email created to send emails to your desired email address, like that each time a new record is being inserted a new email is sent from x@gmail.com to xxx@xxx.xx , where x is an email made for sending and xxx is the receiver.